# What does $\mathbb R \setminus \left\{ 1 \right\}$ mean with respect to a domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

I have a true/false question asking if a composite function's domain is
$\mathbb R \setminus \left\{ 1 \right\}$. 
Whether or not this is true is unimportant. I'm just unfamiliar with the forward slash curly bracket folowing the all real numbers symbol $\mathbb R $. Does anyone know what that $\setminus \left\{ 1 \right\}$ means?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means all real numbers except $1$

Comment: It means all real numbers except for the number one; the slash has two meanings, here it means a set difference, and $\{1\}$ is a set containing only the number one. Sometimes the slash means a quotient set, which is more complex

Comment: Cheers, I haven't taken a maths course in a while and I've forgotten a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

$\{1\}$ is the set containing the single element "1".

The backslash is the "set difference" operator, where $A \setminus B$ is the set of all elements in $A$ that are *not* also in $B$. So $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$ is the set of all real numbers *except* 1.

Comment: "set exclusion" is a better term, IMO :)

Answer (score 1):

Some useful examples to keep in mind:

The set $[0,1] \backslash \{ 1 \}$ coincides with the set $[0,1)$.

The set $[0,1] \backslash \{ 0,1 \}$ coincides with $(0,1)$.

The set $[0,1] \backslash (0,1)$ coincides with $\{ 0,1 \}$.